# Task Dependency in GanttChart

Tags: lightning

I have created Gantt chart in lightning table to show bars based on task start date and end date  using Aura, also the completion rate as shown below, I need to show the dependencies between the tasks (shown in red color in screenshot) .

[image]

these are the different types of dependencies we can have, any idea how this dependencies can be created in lightning?

[image]

In aura we have "lightning:progressBar" to show the progress bar, Do we have any such thing to create this dependencies directly? this is a dynamic table if we try to create this dependencies  line by line, its difficult bcoz we are not sure about the position of next bar, I am not looking for code to implement this, Just some thoughts to discuss on the solution, what approach can be taken.

Comment: is it an Aura component or LWC (Lightning web component) ?

Comment: Its using Aura component

Comment: May I know why the question has been closed? Its quite urgent any help is much appreciated.